# Error: not a function (on mounted)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to implement something to close all menus/modals when a user clicks outside of the menu/modal area.

`this.closeMenu()` is being invoked correctly but I'm getting an error that says `this.closeMenu is not a function`. What's the reason for this?

```
methods: Object.assign({},
  {
    closeMenu(){
      console.log("close menu")
    }
  }
)


mounted(){
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.menu').length){
      // close all menus
      this.closeMenu()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: $(this).closeMenu()?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` keyword here is not `Vue` instance. You can do a trick by assign `var self = this`

```
mounted(){
  var self = this;
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest('.menu').length){
      // close all menus
      self.closeMenu()
    }
  });
}
```